# PCI wifi board (Ubuntu OS) to experiment with microwave signals

Tags: wifi, microwave

I would like to use a PCI WiFi board under Ubuntu OS to experiment with microwave signals.

I would like to be able to access the board through the software driver and be able to turn on or turn off the carriers of the Wi-Fi channels without modulation. In other words, use the board as a microwave signal generator in the Wi-Fi band (2400Mhz-2500Mhz).

I have no idea where to look for information to achieve this if at all possible. Basically I would like to be able to access the records of the chip of the WiFi board by looking at its data sheet (if there is this possibility.)

Comment: It depends heavily on the actual chip used on the board. For the most part you cannot get documentation for the low level operation and even then it would be unlikely you’d get the low level control you want.  Maybe look at a bluetooth chip like a nrf52.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't even attempt this outside of an RF-isolated room, or you're going to disrupt the communication of everyone around (and it's quite likely to be explicitly forbidden by your local regulator).

Answer (score 3):

The manufacturers of WiFi boards are legally required to make this as hard as possible. Control of the actual radios is entirely under control of the internal firmware of the card and is not exposed to the host computer.

Unless you can find a bug in the internal firmware (unlikely) or can figure out how to rewrite the internal firmware (very hard), you just can't do this.

Don't expect any help from a manufacturer. They would be risking their government radio licenses and approvals. Even a company from a relatively unregulated country would be risking losing the ability to sell to a country like the United States or to most of the world.

The reason for these restrictions is that giving the end-user complete control of the radios could cause massive interference with legal users of the radio bands.